# ASP.NET MVC (RAZOR) with Expression Web 4, or at least the option to edit the file?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, expression-web

I have been trying to use expression web lately for editing my HTML files etc...

I.e. use visual studio 2010 for coding and expression web for design.

I thought this was what they were meant for?

Anyway the new extension CSHTML (razor) when i try and open it in expression web it automatically opens it in visual studio.

I am not expecting FULL razor support in expression web but at least the possibility of designing the html embedded in the CSHTML file so i can assign CSS and things like that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For what it's worth, I use expression to get the gist of the markup and then copy that HTML/CSS over to Visual Studio into my views.  Even if Expression can take care of this, it just doesn't seem to do it very well.

Comment: hi there, thanks for the reply.. so you say that you keep a kind of HTML file that you can edit with expression web that you can design normally and when ready you copy it over to the CSHTML file in visual studio?  I presume you keep a copy of the HTML incase you need to change anything?

Comment: @Martin - Exactly.  I version my markup, to a small extent, but keep it all fairly separate from VS, except when I use it in my views of course.

Answer (score 2):

My way to use Expression Web for CSHTML

you need to add the extension cshtml for open that files in Expression Web for setting that you need to configure Expression Web by **Tools > application options > configure editor**

you never can found css class in intellisense by any trick for cshtml but can be view the mockup in the design mode.